# Do mods have the ability to move comments within a Q&A?

Tags: feature-request, comments

As part of some janitorial duties I carry out, a common occurrence I see is where the OP asks more questions using answers.

I've been merging these extra questions into the original question as updates and changing the content to something like:

`[Merged this content into the original question]`

I then flag the answer for the mods to remove. This all works well for 70% of cases and the mods seem happy with this too.

However there are situations like this:

[Copy files from one project to another after build (answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491468/copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-after-build/491534#491534)

There are sometimes a string of comments attached to the answer which have some value. These would need to be moved up to the question to remain in context.

Can the mods do this? Could this functionality be implemented?

Comment: It might not be very good to just merge with the question depending on the number of comments and such. To be merged it needs to be in a line of reasoning. I guess the edit option is better, you can build the additional content in a better way than just merging.

Comment: @bruno - these merges are reasonable. The posts are from the OP asking further questions or adding clarification. This is content that should not be placed in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we can't move those comments.  They'd have to be copied with the other text you're putting in the question, but in a lot of cases they really should have been *answers* to the follow-up part of the question.

On a related note, we do have a new tool to convert answers to comments.  This only works on the latest revision, so if you flag an answer "should have been a comment" please leave the text of the answer in place so we can more easily convert it.

Thanks a lot for doing these "janitorial duties." Keeping the sites clean really is a big help to all of us.

Comment: Can an answer still be converted to a comment if it has comments?

Comment: @shanethehat Yes, and we have the option of moving all the comments along with the answer if we think they're still relevant.